# What's the meaning of "be wheeled around" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> “Miss Maudie, this is an old neighborhood, ain’t it?”
>
> “Been here longer than the town.”
>
> “Nome, I mean the folks on our street are all old. Jem and me’s the only children around here. Mrs. Dubose is close on to a hundred and Miss Rachel’s old and so are you and Atticus.”
>
> “I don’t call fifty very old,” said Miss Maudie tartly. “**Not being wheeled around yet**, am I? Neither’ s your father. But I must say Providence was kind enough to burn down that old mausoleum of mine, I’m too old to keep it up — maybe you’re right, Jean Louise, this is a settled neighborhood. You’ve never been around young folks much, have you?”
>
> *To Kill a Mockingbird*

I dont understand the meaning of "be wheeled around" here. 
Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common usage of the verb *wheel*. From M-W

> [wheel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wheel)
>   : to convey or move on or as if on wheels or in a wheeled vehicle • wheeled the patient back to his room • wheeled the car into the driveway • wheel in the experts

In this context, we can assume that she talking about someone pushing here around on a **wheelchair**, since sometimes older people have a hard time moving around on their own. In a different context, the device could be different, like a stretcher, a wheelbarrow, etc.

Comment: And just to clarify, it's the passive voice being used with **wheel**.  Someone is *wheeling* her, so she is *being wheeled* by someone else.